# Jquery - Server can't read data sent from Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, postman

I am currently sent data using ajax to api server from my web application.
but it's like the server can't read my data because the typeData of my data isn't same with typeData sent by postman.

i'am testing sending data from postman and works perfectly.
here's the capture sending data via postman.

[image]

and here's my ajax code

```
data = {
    nama_lengkap: "user name",
    nama_panggilan: "user",
    ttl: "new york, 10 april 1999",
    jenis_kelamin: "male",
    agama: "-",
    email: "username@mailinator.com",
    no_telp: "1234567",
    nama_ayah: "Johnson",
    nama_ibu: "Kadita",
    pendidikan_terakhir: "S1",
    organisasi: "-",
    kejuaraan: "-",
};

obj = JSON.stringify(data);
t = Cookies.get("user");

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
        accept: "application/json",
    },
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    timeout: 0,
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + t);
    },
    url: "http://localhost:8000/api/anggota/store",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: obj,
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    },
});
```

but I got error responseText like this

```
{
    "success": false,
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Gagal",
    "errors": [
        {
            "nama_lengkap": [
                "The nama lengkap field is required."
            ],
            "nama_panggilan": [
                "The nama panggilan field is required."
            ],
            "ttl": [
                "The ttl field is required."
            ],
            "jenis_kelamin": [
                "The jenis kelamin field is required."
            ],
            "agama": [
                "The agama field is required."
            ],
            "email": [
                "The email field is required."
            ],
            "no_telp": [
                "The no telp field is required."
            ],
            "nama_ayah": [
                "The nama ayah field is required."
            ],
            "nama_ibu": [
                "The nama ibu field is required."
            ],
            "pendidikan_terakhir": [
                "The pendidikan terakhir field is required."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

um, what's wrong with my code? any clues are helps.

Thankyou

Comment: Did you get cross origin error in console?

Comment: there is no cross-origin error in my console.

Comment: running this code in `http://localhost:8000` same port?

Comment: yes. my api and web running in same port. i think the problem isn't from there. because i successfully login, logout, and register. but the data format is FormData not raw json like my code above.

Comment: [Please don't add **SOLVED** to the title of your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101). If it has been solved by an answer, you can accept that answer, if you solved the problem yourself you [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that.

Comment: Ok. i just know that rules. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `Json.Stringify()` !

Just use data Object directly.

Try this:

```
data = {
    nama_lengkap: "user name",
    nama_panggilan: "user",
    ttl: "new york, 10 april 1999",
    jenis_kelamin: "male",
    agama: "-",
    email: "username@mailinator.com",
    no_telp: "1234567",
    nama_ayah: "Johnson",
    nama_ibu: "Kadita",
    pendidikan_terakhir: "S1",
    organisasi: "-",
    kejuaraan: "-",
};

t = Cookies.get("user");

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
        accept: "application/json",
    },
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    timeout: 0,
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + t);
    },
    url: "http://localhost:8000/api/anggota/store",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data,
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    },
});
```

Comment: i already try your method before i am using JSON.stringify() but still not working. and i try to use JSON.stringify because i'm reading article that it says ***"When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string.
Convert a JavaScript object into a string with JSON.stringify()"*** in w3schools

Comment: I said do not use `stringify`.
Secondly Ajax wont accept a String, it only accepts an Object.
You are already sending postman Request with Raw format which is An object

Comment: yes. i got your point. but it's still not working even without stringify.

Comment: make the data Object a `const`
I mean like this :
`const data = {}`

and then write it directly in the ajax function

Comment: is it works????

Comment: still not working. i just re-searching what i am missing in another article or question. i am pretty sure the problem is the type data or format data. postman call api and ajax call little bit different.

Comment: already solved. i still need JSON.Stringify to make it string. my current data is ```data = { nama_lengkap : "user" }```  and convert it to   ```{"nama_lengkap" : "user"}```

Answer (score 0):

see [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

its result is `JSON string`.

Extract from the [official docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}.

So I suggest you use the `object` format when sending to the server.

Comment: is javascript object and JSON object are same?

Answer (score 0):

there is no wrong about the typeData in my code. the main problem is because i  declare  `ContentType: false` in the end of my code.

it should like this

```
$.ajax({
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + t);
            },   
            url: "http://localhost:8000/api/anggota/store",
            method: "POST",
            timeout: 0,
            data: form_anggota,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))
            }
        });
```